# How to find a number between two numbers based on a proportion.

Tags: ratio

I'm making a game about colors, and recently ran into a simple problem. When the player collides with a block, the players speed increases based on how red the block is.
I have a variable called red, which is between 0 and 1, a predefined variable called normalSpeed and maxSpeed, and one called speed.
speed should be between normalSpeed and maxSpeed based on the red.
if red = 1, speed would equal maxSpeed. 
What's an equation to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the the new speed depend on the current speed? Or will the new speed simply be a function of the redness, regardless of the current speed of the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

speed = normal speed + red (maxspeed - normal speed )

when red is $0$, speed = normal speed.

when red is $1$, speed = max speed.

if red is in between $0$ and $1$, you obtain something in between.